# Python - How do you use getattr to call an variable object?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, getattr

I've searched through a large number of links on how to use the getattr function in python and understand that it can be used to call functions as per below;

```
for attr in ['title', 'author']:
    getattr(b, attr)
```

which is equivalent to;

```
b.title
b.author
```

My question is how do you dynamically refer to an object; `b`

i.e. I know that I will be calling the function `some_function()`, but the object could be `a`,`b`, or `c`. Note a, b, and c are all part of the same Class; just different instances.

I won't know until runtime which I will need to call.

Comment: *a, b, and c are all part of the same Class; just different instances*...not clear to me?...like instances of other classes?

Comment: How do you know which of `a`, `b` or `c` you have to use?

Comment: The best way is don't use variables called `a`, `b` and `c`.  Instead, use a dictionary whose keys are `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.

Comment: Iron fist; so, to give some context, I'm creating a game, and each player can 'log in'. A, B and C represent the different players.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 'some_function' will also be determined at runtime and the name put into a variable:

```
fname = 'some_function'

for obj in objlist:
    method = getattr(obj, fname, None)
    if method is None:
        continue

    method()  # you can also put this into a try block
```

`getattr` on obj gives you a bound method and that means it can be directly referenced and called.

Answer (score 0):

set the `some_function` an `obj` parameter and use in the `getattr`:

```
def some_function(obj):
    for attribute in ['title', 'author']:
        getattr(obj, attribute)
```